# How to stop a user from closing a reward ad with back press

Tags: java, android, admob, rewardedvideoad

I have an app that will show Admob reward videos and interstellar ads, but I noticed that a user can simply press the back button and the ad will close. is there anyway to prevent the ad from closing by just clicking the back button i tried using the onBackPressed() method with no luck

```
public class EarnActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RewardedVideoAdListener{
  private RewardedVideoAd mAd;
  private boolean showing;


 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.earn);
        runAd();


    }
```

this is the method to run the ad

```
private void runAd(){

 MobileAds.initialize(this, "App ID");

 mAd = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(this);
 mAd.setRewardedVideoAdListener(this);
 loadRewardVideoAd();
 mAd.show();


}

loadRewardVideoAd(){

  if(!mAd.isLoaded())
        {
             mAd.loadAd("ad-number", new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        }

}
```

and these are my @Override methods including the onbackpressed method

```
 @Override
 public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() {

 }

 @Override
 public void onRewardedVideoAdOpened() {

 }

 @Override
 public void onRewardedVideoStarted() {
  showing = true;
 }

 @Override
 public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed() {
     loadRewardVideoAd();
     showing = false;
 }

 @Override
 public void onRewarded(RewardItem rewardItem) {

 }

 @Override
 public void onRewardedVideoCompleted(){

 }

 @Override
 public void onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication() {

 }

 @Override
 public void onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int i) {

     loadRewardVideoAd();
 }

 @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {

    if(showing){

   }else{
     super.onBackPressed();

   }
 }

}
```

Comment: you should not prevent user from canceling rewarded AD. Instead you should cancel his reward in case if he cancels the AD.

Comment: Thats true but it is also needed for interstellar ads

Answer (score 0):

Another way, it's trying to override `onKeyEvent`. However, just make sure what you are doing with it.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
 if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

   return true;
 }
   return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);    
}
```

Comment: this does not so solve the problem it does exactly the same thing as my example. im trying to stop an open ad from being closed when the user press the back button

Comment: @user3404816 How this add is implemented? Is it transparent activity, or dialog activity?